# Can we configure Maven in existing project?

Tags: eclipse, maven, struts2, m2eclipse

I am working in Struts 2 and Hibernate 3 based project, we had developed many modules (includes many JSP pages), now I want to use Maven in my current project.

So is it possible in my current project that I will configure Maven in my current project? If so, then please explain me steps for that if possible.

I am using Eclipse 3.5, Struts 2, Hibernate 3 and jasper-report 3.7.3 for my project.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is.

Two options:

- Change your folder structure to use the default maven folder structure (src/main/java, etc.)
- Or, set up in your pom.xml different source folder configurations

I would go for the first option if not too painful.

Then, use M2_ECLIPSE plugin to keep you eclipse conf in synch with the maven conf.

Don't commit eclipse project files (.settings, .project, .casspath) to SCM, pom.xml has to be the "master"

Comment: Thanks for reply.... i so as u had explain that 1st option is good so how would be we  have to set maven folder structure?? whats the maven folder structure??

Comment: @Sanju [This](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html) is the Maven standard directory layout. If your really want to use maven you should consider to understand the basic's first. If you have no idea about the directory structure I would recommend to read some apache/sonatype documentation first before trying to adopt maven for your projects :-)